# a method keeps asking for input when i didnt even ask the user for input

Tags: java, for-loop

hey i am solving a problem on codingbat called sumDigits where u make a method which sums the digits of a number 
for example 
123 should return 1 + 2 +3 // 6
here is the code

```
public int sumDigits(int num ) // num = 123
    {
        int sumOfDigits = 0;

        for(int i = num ; i >= 0 ; i /= 10)
        {
            int digit = i % 10; // stores the rightmost digit then adds it to sumOfDigits
            sumOfDigits += digit;
        }
        return sumOfDigits;

    }
```

Main Function:-

```
System.out.println("Problem 4");
Assignment5 solutionA5 = new Assignment5();
System.out.println(solutionA5.sumDigits(123));
```

the problem is , when i run the program 
and the num parameter is = 123 as i wrote in the comment 
the program waits for the user to enter another num ! 
i dont understand why , i didnt even include any scanner in.nextInt or anything like that ? 
sorry if its a lame question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the program waits for the user to enter another num

No it doesn't. It enters an *infinite loop*, because `i` can never become negative. Your loop should be:

```
for (int i = num; i > 0; i /= 10)
```

What 'enter another num' can possibly mean in a program that doesn't accept user input at all is another mystery.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot !
it didnt cross my mind that this would cause an infinite loop actually

Answer (score 0):

It goes into infinite loop one the value of `i=0` . You shall change

```
for(int i = num ; i >= 0 ; i /= 10)
```

to

```
for(int i = num ; i > 0 ; i /= 10)
```

---

> i didnt even include any scanner in.nextInt

Its not waiting for the user input either. All it does is this:

```
System.out.println("Problem 4"); // prints 'Problem 4'
Assignment5 solutionA5 = new Assignment5();
System.out.println(solutionA5.sumDigits(123)); // goes into the infinite loop
```

Comment: Yes thanks a lot !
it didnt cross my mind that this would cause an infinite loop actually

Comment: @ShaDiliX SO is meant for that only.

Comment: well i keep asking newbies questions and keep getting down voted ... so frustrating